# Product image in cart

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need product image in shopping cart. Now I have only product name there. Here is the link - http://layot.prestatrend.com/
And here is the code for product's name at the cart:

```
//if product is not in the displayed cart, add a new product's line
                    var domIdProduct = this.id + (this.idCombination ? '_' + this.idCombination : '');
                var domIdProductAttribute = this.id + '_' + (this.idCombination ? this.idCombination : '0');
                if($('#cart_block_top dt#cart_block_top_product_'+ domIdProduct ).length == 0)
                {
                    var productId = parseInt(this.id);
                    var productAttributeId = (this.hasAttributes ? parseInt(this.attributes) : 0);
                    var content =  '<dt class="hidden" id="cart_block_top_product_' + domIdProduct + '">';
                        content += '<span class="quantity-formated"><span class="quantity">' + this.quantity + '</span>x</span>';
                        var name = (this.name.length > 12 ? this.name.substring(0, 10) + '...' : this.name);
                        content += '<a href="' + this.link + '" title="' + this.name + '">' + name + '</a>';
                        content += '<span class="remove_link"><a rel="nofollow" class="ajax_cart_block_top_remove_link" href="' + baseDir + 'cart.php?delete&amp;id_product=' + productId + '&amp;token=' + static_token + (this.hasAttributes ? '&amp;ipa=' + parseInt(this.idCombination) : '') + '"> </a></span>';
                        content += '<span class="price">' + this.priceByLine + '</span>';
                        content += '</dt>';
                    if (this.hasAttributes)
                        content += '<dd id="cart_block_top_combination_of_' + domIdProduct + '" class="hidden"><a href="' + this.link + '" title="' + this.name + '">' + this.attributes + '</a>';
                    if (this.hasCustomizedDatas)
                        content += ajaxCart.displayNewCustomizedDatas(this);
                    if (this.hasAttributes) content += '</dd>';
                    $('#cart_block_top dl.products').append(content);
                }
```

So could anybody help to parse product image in the cart?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create an image placeholder on

`$('#cart_block_top dt#cart_block_top_product_'+ domIdProduct )` .

Then you can send source of image as this.image source. Something like this:

```
 content += '<img src="' + this.imageSource' />';
```

Grab `imageSource` as you are assign them to `.product_image`.

just send this product image src to `displayNewProducts` function.

Comment: Why you don't you append instead of `content +=`?